# Emplty plot normalised values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, normalization

Want to plot normalised values in array but getting empty plot

```
import numpy as np
x_array = np.array([2,3,5,6,7,4,8,7,6])
normalized_arr = preprocessing.normalize([x_array])
print(normalized_arr)

plt.plot(normalized_arr)
plt.show()
```

Empty plot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnSbI.png

Is there function that can fill the empty plot with values?

Comment: What's `preprocessing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change your code into:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
x_array = np.array([2,3,5,6,7,4,8,7,6])
normalized_arr = preprocessing.normalize([x_array])
print(normalized_arr)

plt.plot(x_array.reshape(-1,1),normalized_arr.reshape(-1,1))
plt.show()
```

##### Output

[image: The output image]